# dplyr::full_join two data frames with part-match in the "by" argument in R

Tags: r, dplyr, merge, fuzzyjoin

I would like to join two data sets that look like the following data sets. The matching rule would be that the `Item` variable from `mykey` matches the first part of the `Item` entry in `mydata` to some degree.

```
mydata <- tibble(Item = c("ab_kssv", "ab_kd", "cde_kh", "cde_ksa", "cde"), 
             Answer = c(1,2,3,4,5), 
             Avg = rep(-100, length(Item)))

mykey <- tibble(Item = c("ab", "cde"), 
            Avg = c(0 ,10))
```

The result should be the following:

```
  Item    Answer   Avg
1 ab_kssv      1     0
2 ab_kd        2     0
3 cde_kh       3    10
4 cde_ksa      4    10
5 cde          5    10
```

I looked at [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29172992/merge-data-frames-in-r-with-custom-id-match-criterion) [three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29791726/inexact-merge-of-two-data-frames-by-row-name-in-r) [SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35814850/closest-match-of-a-sentence-between-two-data-frames-in-r), but did not find a nice solution there. I also briefly tried the [fuzzyjoin package](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/fuzzyjoin/versions/0.1.6), but that did not work. Finally, I have a for-loop-based solution:

```
for (currLine in 1:nrow(mydata)) {
mydata$Avg[currLine] <- mykey$Avg[str_starts(mydata$Item[currLine], mykey$Item)]
}
```

It does the job, but is not nice to read / understand and **I wonder if there is a possibility to make the "by" argument of `full_join()` from the [dplyr package](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/1.0.10) a bit more tolerant with its matching.** Any help will be apreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a `fuzzyjoin::regex_left_join` you could do:

Note: I renamed the `Item` column in your `mykey` dataset to `regex` to make clear that this is the regex to match by and added a `"^"` to ensure that we match at the beginning of the `Item` column in the `mydata` dataset.

```r
library(fuzzyjoin)
library(dplyr)

mykey <- mykey %>%
  rename(regex = Item) %>%
  mutate(regex = paste0("^", regex))

mydata %>%
  select(-Avg) %>%
  regex_left_join(mykey, by = c(Item = "regex")) %>%
  select(-regex)
#> # A tibble: 5 × 3
#>   Item    Answer   Avg
#>   <chr>    <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 ab_kssv      1     0
#> 2 ab_kd        2     0
#> 3 cde_kh       3    10
#> 4 cde_ksa      4    10
#> 5 cde          5    10
```

Comment: Cool, thanks, that's much more elegant and human-readable!